# Print variable after closing the file in Perl

Tags: perl

Below code works fine but I want `$ip` to be printed after closing the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;

my $file = "/tmp/example";

open(FILE, "<$file") or die $!;

while ( <FILE> ) {

    my $lines = $_;

    if ( $lines =~ m/address/ ) {
        my ($string, $ip) = (split ' ', $lines);
        print "IP address is: $ip\n";
    }
}

close(FILE);
```

sample data in /tmp/example file

```
 $cat /tmp/example
 country us 
 ip_address  192.168.1.1
 server  dell
```

Comment: If you need IP to be printed after the close. It is out of scope. So that you may declare the $ip variable globally or before the loop gets starts

Comment: Give me a sample input data in a file, that would be easier for us

Comment: sample data in file in each line: country us 
ip_address  192.168.1.1
server  dell

Comment: Edited the question with /tmp/example file details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all ips in an array and you'll then have it for later processing.
The shown code can also be simplified a lot. This assumes a four-number ip and data like that shown in the sample

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = '/tmp/example';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @ips;

while (<$fh>) {
     if (my ($ip) = /ip_address\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/) {
         push @ips, $ip;
     }
}
close $fh;

say for @ips;
```

Or, once you open the file, process all lines with a `map`

```
my @ips = map { /ip_address\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ } <$fh>;
```

The filehandle is here read in a list context, imposed by `map`, so all lines from the file are returned.  The block in `map` applies to each in turn, and `map` returns a flattened list with results.

Some notes

- Use three-argument `open`, it is better
- Don't assign `$_` to a variable. To work with a lexical use `while (my $line = <$fh>)`
- You can use `split` but here regex is more direct and it allows you to assign its match so that it is scoped.  If there is no match the `if` fails and nothing goes onto the array

Answer (score 2):

This solution looks for the first line that contains `ip_address` followed by some space and a sequence of digits and dots

Wrapping the search in a block makes perl delete the lexical variable `$fh`. Because it is a file handle, that handle will also be automatically closed

Note that I've used `autodie` to avoid the need to explicitly check the status of the `open` call

This algorithm will find the *first* occurrence of `ip_address` and stop reading the file immediately

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my $file = '/tmp/example';

my $ip;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $file;

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        if ( /ip_address\h+([\d.]+)/ ) {
            $ip = $1;
            last;
        }
    }
}

print $ip // 'undef', "\n";
```

#### output

```
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using another scope? If we use multiple files there we use the scope. For this program, File handle will automatically close when the program terminate. Please explain is there any other reason.?

Answer (score 0):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "test";
my ( $string,$ip);
open my $FH, "<",$file) or die $!;
while (my $lines = <FH>) {
 if ($lines =~ m/address/){
   ($string, $ip) = (split ' ', $lines);
  }
 }

print "IP address is: $ip\n";
```

This will give you the output you needed. But fails in the case of multiple IP match lines in the input file overwrites the last $ip variable.

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $ip in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 15.
IP address is:`  $ip is not printing and getting an error

Comment: @Premchand: **Harini's** code isn't great, but it does work given the data in your question. You must have made a mistake to get that *Use of uninitialized value* error.

Comment: There is no error I get that you specified here@Premchand